# Is it possible to delete a primary key without causing Integrity error on foreign key table?

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a model1 whose primary key is referred as foreign key (ste_id) in model2 as follows:

```
...
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    ste_id = models.ForeignKey(
        SimulatorTrainingEnvironment,
        related_name="environmenthistory",
        on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        default="",
    )
...
```

Can I delete the primary key from model1 without causing Integrity Error?

Comment: Normally the database will raise an integrity erro, exactly because the item refers to a history that no longer exists, so no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be [SET_NULL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.SET_NU) is what you are looking for

```py
...
on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
...
```

[doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.SET_NU)